# Can I use 'forces' in a political context? If not, what can I use instead?

Tags: word-request

I doubt I can use the word 'forces' in a political context (neither Lexico nor Google News supports this view). How can I substitute it? 'Parties' is too narrow. Parties, voting blocs, and whatnot — how do you describe it collectively? As in

> center-right/center-left etc. ***forces***

Comment: I’d need more context to be sure, but “groups” or “elements” may be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Possibly "factions," but I agree that this question needs more context

Comment: Definitely could use more context.  One option is to drop the noun altogether and treat "centre-right/centre-left" as a noun instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get why you discard the word **forces** so easily.

What about the 4.4 in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/force), the dictionary that you mentioned?

> A group of people brought together and organized for a **particular activity**.

Such **activity** may be making America great again or supporting medicare for all, for example. A specific party and its supporters, or even a **faction** (as suggested by Katy) inside a party, can be described as a force.

In some of the examples provided in the linked page, you can find a "political context"

> *In reality, it brought together some of the world's most socially **conservative religious forces***

You haven't shown us the full context, the sentence that you want to write using the term that you're looking for. Maybe if you improve your question adding a bit of information about that, you can get a better help.

Comment: “Forces” is often short for *armed* forces. If you’re in a context where that could make sense, another word would be preferred.

Comment: I don't have meaning 4.4 (https://jpeg.im/gltp). I guess it's in the BrE version